# How to keep data persistent in a while loop, especially when the data is assigned to a variable in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, pygame

I am building a simple game in Pygame, and given below is my code fragment for checking events within the game.

```
class Opening:
    """
    Functions for moving the cursor on the opening screen.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.state = 1

    def check_event(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # For exiting out of the game.
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            # For moving the cursor.
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    print("Down")
                    self.state = 2
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    print("UP")
                    self.state = 1

# Debug
if __name__ == '__main__':

    pygame.init()

    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), 0, 8)

    while True:
        fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        surface.fill((128, 254, 192))
        print(Opening().state)
        pygame.display.update()
        fps_clock.tick(60)
```

The events are part of a menu, which is why, I need to keep the state of a variable fixed even while inside a loop. Right now, with every iteration of the loop, the value for Opening().state gets overriden.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: `Opening()` creates a new object. Create the object before the loop `opening = Opening()` and use the object `opening`

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`Opening()` constructs a new [instance objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of the class `Opening`. Create the object before the application loop (`opening = Opening()`) and use the object `opening` in the loop:

```py
opening = Opening()

while True:
   
    # [...]

    print(opening.state)
```